# How to loop through messages and delete certain ones in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase and want to loop through my messages that I have and delete certain ones based upon a user's uid.

Here is an image of what I have for the structure of my data:
[image]

So far I know you would start of as something like:

```
Firebase.database().ref('messages').on('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
   if(snap.val().user.id === currentUser.uid){
    //delete message here
  };
 });
});
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you probably want to use [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once) instead of [on()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on).  If you modify the contents of the database that you're working with, your on() will get triggered again for each change.  You can see how that might be problematic for your case, if you only want to loop through the data once.  Definitely learn about the difference between once() and on().

If you have a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) type object, you can delete the contents of the database at its location with

```
snap.ref.remove()
```

Definitely read up on the [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) object type.

Comment: So all i would do inside would be `snap.ref('message/user/id' + snap.val().user.id).remove()`, inside the if statement there correct?

Comment: I think i found it out it would be `firebase.database().ref('messages/' + snap.key).remove()`

Comment: If you want to do extra typing.  A ref is a ref no matter how you got it.